# What was the Freezer & Cold Planet Trade Organization's profit in Dragon Ball series?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In [this article](http://dbzuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Trade_Organization) it is told that Freezer's family conquered planets and traded them.

What did they expect in exchange for a planet being sold? Was there a universal currency or goods they would want in exchange, when they had control over entire worlds?

Comment: I think her name was Freiza- that's how I always aw it spelled- just thought to let you know.

Comment: I fix it later. I speak spanish and here tv shows spell it Freezer

Comment: In Japanese it was pronounced as _Furiiza_, which is "freezer", but the US version spelled it "Frieza". It was either a mistake or an attempt to take away some of the jokey feel of the Japanese version. Interesting that the Spanish version uses "Freezer".

Answer (score 1):

It was always my impression that they were bartered for more power/ soldiers for their army. Frieza (Freezer) has many followers, of many races from many different planets. I always thought they must have joined after a planet Frieza conquered was traded, and the group it was traded to supplied them with soldiers. It could also stand to reason they could be used to mine for resources, harvested for life energy, or used as colonies for further expansion of their empire.